# Chamada javascript de dentro do code behind não funciona

Tags: javascript, c#

Essa é minha função:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(dt_exclusao) {

            var arrData = dt_exclusao.split('/');
            var exclusaoFormatada = arrData[1] + '-' + arrData[0] + '-' + arrData[2];
            var dias = parseInt(prazoSubPrestador);
            var novaData = new Date(arrData[2], arrData[1] - 1, arrData[0]);

            novaData.setDate(novaData.getDate() + dias);

            hoje = new Date(novaData)
            dia = hoje.getDate()
            mes = hoje.getMonth()
            ano = hoje.getFullYear()
            if (dia < 10)
                dia = "0" + dia

            if ((mes + 1) < 10)
                mes = "0" + (mes + 1);

            if (ano < 2000)
                ano = "19" + ano

            var dt = dia + "/" + (mes) + "/" + ano;

            document.getElementById('lblPrazoSubsAns').innerHTML = "Prazo de substituição: " + dt;
        }
    </script>
```

E essa é minha chamada:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MontaDataExclusaoPrazoANS", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(calDataExclusao.Date)", true);
```

O que passa é que não sobe nada, o label não é alterado. A funcção funciona, mas não dessa forma. tentei chamar direto no aspx, mas não deu certo. Abaixo o meu aspx e não sei onde chamar. Apenas o código da combo para chamar a função.

```
<table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:30%; text-align:right">Motivo:</td>
                        <td style="width:70%"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMotivoExclusao" runat="server" Width="400px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMotivoExclusao_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="trDataNotificacaoExclusaoVoluntaria" runat="server" visible="false">
                        <td style="text-align:right">Data Notificação da Exclusão Voluntária:<span style="color:Red">*</span></td>
                        <td><cc1:Calendario id="calDataNotificacaoExclusaoVoluntaria" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:right">Data Exclusão:</td>
                        <td>
                            <cc1:Calendario id="calDataExclusao" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="calDataExclusao_TextChanged" />
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPrazoSubsAns">Teste:</asp:Label>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidQtdeDiasExclusao" runat="server" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidIndLEI13003" runat="server" />
                        </td>
......
```

Comment: A chamada chega no JS? Outro ponto, vi que você está passando o parâmetro no JS de modo estranho, tenta assim cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MontaDataExclusaoPrazoANS", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador("+DateTime.Now+")", true);

Comment: Sim.. Mas do modo que você está passando, está indo como STRING e nao como DATA.

Comment: Calma... o que você quer fazer? diga em poucas palavras. O que você fez chega a chamar o método Javascript?

Comment: Preciso carregar uma data vinda oracle. Essa data ela é uma composição com data_exclusão + um valor parametrizado. No banco isso tá ok. No asp também tá funcionando e no MVC. Porém no aspx não. Veja que o sistema é um remendão. Não consigo chamar a função, porém a função js que passei tem erro e isso já corrigi e ainda não funcionou. Essa é a minha necessidade.

Comment: Certo,  Quando você faz isso  -> cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MontaDataExclusaoPrazoANS", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(calDataExclusao.Date)", true); A função chega no Javascript?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, dá esse erro que não consigo ir até onde está o erro: `Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. O script não está sendo chamado. Coloquei um `alert();` na primeira linha e nada.

Comment: Tenta chamar assim cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MontaDataExclusaoPrazoANS", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(null)", true);

Comment: Nada, não disparou o `alert();`.

Comment: Tenta chamar assim então cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MontaDataExclusaoPrazoANS", "<script>montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(null)</script>", true);

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, cara tá osso o negócio aqui. Também não disparou o `alert();`. O alert é a primeira linha da função.

Comment: Só pra constar... você chega a executar a a linha  abaixo ?cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MontaDataExclusaoPrazoANS", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(calDataExclusao.Date)", true);

Comment: Sim, vou com F10 e passa pela linha sim. Porém eu apanhei bastante antes com javascript, devido ao cache do chrome. E só consegui resolver com o reiniciar da máquina. Em último caso, farei isso.

Comment: Minha última cartada, vê se assim funciona ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "_montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(null);", true);

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, dessa forma funfou. O alert(); subiu. Agora vou debugar e saber porque não alterou o label, mas isso é outra coisa. O importante é que a função foi chamada. Para o título da pergunta, a sua sugestão funcionou. Coloque como resposta para eu fachar o post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim e vê assim funciona

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "_montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(calDataExclusao.Date);", true);
```

Comment: ele só não aceita quando eu concateno uma variável assim: `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "_montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador", "montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(" + nova_data + ");", true);`